# Grouping a generic list by 2 values and concatenation from a single dataset via LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: linq, lambda, vb.net-2010

Definition of my Class

```
    Public Class ProcessAlert
       Public LoanNumber As String
       Public EmailAddress As String
       Public AlertType As String
       Public AlertMethodID As Byte
    End Class
```

A generic list that is representative of data returned from DB

```
     Dim a As New List(Of ProcessAlert)

     a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Alert", 2))
     a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Document", 2))
     a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Note", 2))
     a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Alert", 1))
     a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Document", 1))
     a.Add(New ProcessAlert("0000112367", "jdoe@home.com", "Note", 1))

     Return a
```

I managed this LINQ statement that will group by LoanNumber and EmailAddress but I can't get the AlertType to show up as a concatenated field of all 3 values

```
     Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(g) New With {Key .A = g.LoanNumber, Key .B = g.EmailAddress})
```

This code will give me a grouping by EmailAddress and the values I need of:
        "jdoe@home.com", "Alert, Document, Note"
        "5551110000@txt.att.net", "Alert, Document, Note"

```
    Dim res = Alerts.GroupBy(Function(i) i.EmailAddress).Select(Function(g) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(g.Key, String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(x) x.AlertType).ToArray())))
```

But I cannot seem to get the statement give me a return that looks like this:

```
    "0000112367","jdoe@home.com", "Alert, Document, Note"
    "0000112367","5551112222@txt.att.net", "Alert, Document, Note"
```

How do I get 2 fields to group and then concatenate the values of AlertType into a single field???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
From _a In a
Group _a.AlertType By _a.LoanNumber, _a.EmailAddress Into Group
Select New With
{
    .LoanNumber = LoanNumber,
    .EmailAddress = EmailAddress,
    .AlertTypes = String.Join(", ", Group.ToArray())
}
```